# <serverVariables> <set name="..."/> breaks web.config

Tags: iis, ssl, seo, web-config, redirect

**There's a TL;DR at the bottom of the question!**

Here goes...

The background to the issue (put simply) is that IIS Rewrite drops the protocol in redirect actions. So a rule with `<action type="Redirect" url="whatever"/>` goes from https to http if you don't explicitly specify the protocol in `url="..."`, like so `url="https://{HOST}"`.

After much Googleing around, I found **[this article](http://blogs.iis.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action)**, which describes a variety of ways to keep the protocol when redirecting. The method that will work best for me is as follows:

```xml
<rule name="Create HTTP_PROTOCOL">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_PROTOCOL" value="{C:1}" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localtest\.me$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_PROTOCOL}://www.localtest.me/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

...this is the case for 2 reasons:

1. there are multiple rules that will need to maintain the protocol. Writing 2 of each (one for http only and another for https) would be unfeasible.
2. this file must work on direct SSL connections (where {HTTP}=on) and be compatible with Cloudflare's flexible SSL (where {HTTP}=off but {HTTP_X-Forwarded-Proto} is either "http" or "https").

SO,

The idea is to set a variable I can use against a rewriteMap. And the value of that variable depends on `HTTPS=on` OR `HTTP_X-Forwarded-Proto=https`

Here is my original code, which drops the protocol:

```xml
<!-- remove trailing slashes looses protocol -->
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/+$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And here is my modified code, which redirects with the required protocol whether there is a direct SSL connection or the connection comes in via CloudFlare's Flexible SSL:

```xml
<!-- rewrite config -->
<rewrite>

  <!-- rewrite maps -->
  <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="RedirectBase">
          <add key="http" value="http://{HTTP_HOST}/" />
          <add key="https" value="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" />
      </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>

  <!-- rewrite rules -->
  <rules>

    <!-- capture incoming protocol -->
    <rule name="HTTP_PROTOCOL - Capture Default">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
      </conditions>
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_PROTOCOL" value="{C:1}" />
      </serverVariables>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>

    <!-- overwrite protocol var if using CloudFlare's flexible SSL -->
    <rule name="HTTP_PROTOCOL - Overwrite with CloudFlare header">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Forwarded-Proto}" pattern="^https$" />
      </conditions>
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_PROTOCOL" value="{C:1}" replace="true" />
      </serverVariables>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>

    <!-- remove trailing slashes but keep protocol -->
    <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)/+$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{RedirectBase:{HTTP_PROTOCOL}}{R:1}" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Except,

A) I get a blank page, url rewrite fails, no error information.

B) But it works if I remove both instances of this tag:

**TL;DR** Why doesn't this work?

```xml
  <serverVariables>
    <set name="HTTP_PROTOCOL" value="something" />
  </serverVariables>
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer!

I had to **manually add "HTTP_PROTOCOL" to the list of allowed server variables** in the URL Rewrite config. It seems this can only be done via the IIS UI and not via the web.config file. **[Full instructions here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables)**.

Answer (score 0):

Seems server variables are is "server" config, not "web" config.

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/755416cd-9085-4158-bf34-8593904edfa4/how-can-i-define-a-server-variable-in-webconfig?forum=iisurlrewritemodule

> When you add a server variable from IIS Manager. It writes to `applicationHost.config` file by default. It is located at `%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`. Please check if the server variable is rightly defined there.

> You can manually define a server variable by adding the following entry to `applicationHost.config` file:

```
<location path="your site name">
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="server variable name" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```